# 12c Grid Agent installation issues - Shell path is incorrect or not defined

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-grid-control

I am installing 12c Grid Control agent on my server via Enterprise manager.

The targer server is a UNIX server with AIX OS on it. I add target host manually, enter authentication information, host name, installation directory, etc. and all goes well untill I click "Deploy Agent" button, then I get the following error:

"Shell path is incorrect or not defined.:/bin/bash(SH_PATH),-c(SH_ARGS) on host MyHostName"

and details are :

"Check the property values in the following files in this order, ssPaths_.properties or sPaths.properties or Paths.properties, in "/u02/app/oracle/middleware/oms/oui/prov/resources"

There isn't /u02/app" directory on my target server, only /u01/app/oracle" so I assume the above directory is on the same server as Enterprise manager.

Although I did find a directory where I have files of the format  ssPaths_.properties  - /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/oui/prov/resources

Since my platform ia AIX, I used file   ssPaths_aix.properties

On my target server if I run which bash I get /usr/bin/bash and which ssh returns /usr/bin/ssh ahd which sh returns /usr/bin/sh

So I edited the ssPaths_aix.properties file so that SH_PATH=/usr/bin/sh  but still getting the same error. I have also tried setting to SH_PATH=/usr/bin/bash but nothing seems to make any difference. I am thinking one possibility would be I am editing wrong file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you've got root access, symbolic link your bash binary so there's a link at /bin/bash

Answer (score -2):

try the following doc 
EM 12c Agent Push Fails With Shell Path is Incorrect or Not Defined : /bin/bash(SH_PATH),-c(SH_ARGS) (Doc ID 1489437.1)

Comment: Please tell us the contents of that document.